# Can't login to Facebook using fbchat in Python

Tags: python

Today I'm trying to login to my account with fbchat. I am using my account on my browser. I ran this code

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *
client = Client("USER", "PASS")
```

and error appeared:

```
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_client.py", line 209, in login
    user_agent=user_agent,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_state.py", line 153, in login
    "(Failed on url: {})".format(r.url)
fbchat._exception.FBchatUserError: Login failed. Check email/password. (Failed on url: https://m.facebook.com/checkpoint/?_rdr)
```

When I login on the browser, I had to verify my indentity. After verifying, I ran the code again but it didn't work.
I have looked through some posts and I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Do you happen to have 2FA enabled?

Comment: 2FA is not turned on!

Comment: Try adding session cookies in Client constructor. Look here for code https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat/issues/292

Answer (score 0):

Go to the fbchat file it will be like this path:

```
\lib\site-packages\fbchat_state.py
```

On line 190 in change:

```
revision = int(r.text.split('"client_revision":', 1)[1].split(",", 1)[0])
```

To:

```
revision = 1
```

After that, try to use your code, for example:

```
from fbchat import Client
client = Client('email', 'password')
```